# Derivative of a parallel translation inside a metric

Tags: derivatives, riemannian-geometry

> Let $M$ be a riemannian manifold with metric $g$ and a connection
>    $\nabla$ on $M$.  Let $X,Y$ two vector fields along a curve $\gamma$
>    on $M$. Let $$\tau_{t,s}:T_{\gamma(s)}M\to T_{\gamma(t)}M$$ the
>    parallel translation along $\gamma$. We consider the fonction
>    $$F(t)=g(\gamma(t))(\tau_{t,s} X(\gamma(s)), \tau_{t,s}
>  Y(\gamma(s))).$$ Then
>    $$F'(s)=g(\gamma(t))\left(\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=s}\tau_{t,s}
>  X(\gamma(s)),
>  \tau_{t,s}Y(\gamma(s))\right)+g(\gamma(t))\left(\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=s}\tau_{t,s}
>  Y(\gamma(s)), \tau_{t,s}X(\gamma(s))\right)+\dot\gamma\left[g(X,Y)\right](\gamma(s)) \ (\star).$$

I do not understand why this identity holds. Here is what I have tried so far:

Let $$a(t)=\tau_{t,s} X(\gamma(s))=a_i(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_{\gamma(t)}\text{ and }b(t)=\tau_{t,s} Y(\gamma(s))=b_j(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_{\gamma(t)},$$
so $F(t)=g(\gamma(t))(a(t),b(t))$. If we let
$$g_{ij}(t)=g(\gamma(t))\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_{\gamma(t)}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\bigg|_{\gamma(t)}\right),$$
we find that $F(t)=a_i(t)b_j(t)g_{ij}(t)$, thus the derivative of $F$ is
$$F'(s)=a_i'(s)b_j(s)g_{ij}(s)+a_i(s)b_j'(s)g_{ij}(s)+a_i(s)b_j(s)g'_{ij}(s).$$
The first two terms give the first two terms of $(\star)$, but what about the **last one** ? We have that
$$\dot\gamma\left[g(X,Y)\right](\gamma(s))=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=s} g(\gamma(t))(X(\gamma(t)),Y(\gamma(t))),$$
right ? This does not seem equal to $a_i(s)b_j(s)g'_{ij}(s)$... ?

Comment: Your definition of $F(t)$ doesn't make sense unless $s = \epsilon$. This in turn causes problems with your expression for $F'(s)$.

Comment: You mean $t$ close enough to $s$ ? It was implicitly assumed.

Comment: My fault, I thought your subscript $s$ was an $\epsilon$ (hard for me to see those tiny subscripts). It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula was wrong in the book...